# Why won't Rails deserialize my field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, serialization

I am using the [Classifier:Bayes](http://classifier.rubyforge.org/) as part of a model class. I have the class set up to serialize the classifier to the db.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :classifier
end
```

The yaml appears in the db just fine after doing some training and saving the object.

But when I query for the class, instance.classifier is a string

```
@f = Foo.find(params[:id])
@f.classifier.class   # is String
```

I was under the impression that Rails / ActiveRecord would magically deserialize my classifier for me. Is there some setting I need to tweak or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past, I've had to add the class name to the method args...

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :classifier, Classifier::Bayes
end
```